# irritating validation ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hello I'm newbie in ruby on rails I having problem in validation of old password. if I'm going to go in edit account page and if I save it the validation of old password show even though edit account page and change password page are different pages but they share in one model. pls help me.

**here is my model:**

```
validates_presence_of :firstname, :message => 'First Name is required'
  validates_format_of :firstname, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]|\d)*\Z/, :message => 'First name must not contain special characters'
  validates_presence_of :lastname, :message => 'Last Name is required'
  validates_format_of :lastname, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]|\d)*\Z/, :message => 'Lastname name must not contain special characters'
  validates_presence_of :email, :message => 'Email Address is required'
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => 'Email address is already taken, please select a new one'
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "Please enter a valid email address"
  validates_presence_of :username, :message => 'Username is required'
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :message => 'Username is already taken, please select a new one'
  validates_length_of :username, :within => 3..15, :message => "Username must be at least 3 - 15 characters in length", :on => :create


  validates_presence_of :password_old, :on => :update, :message => "Old password is required"
```

if you need more info just comment.... thanks in advance.

Comment: Please write the question properly. I'm not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: I have page the edit account page and change password page..they share in the same model the "user.rb" whenever I put validation in old_password it shows in edit account page which is edit account is a different page and it doesn't have oldp_password

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that it should not check for password while updating account information. 
You can write a conditional validation which will check for the old_password if user has provided new password in change password field.

```
validates_presence_of :password_old, :on => :update, :unless => :current_password.nil?,:message => "Old password is required"
```

Comment: I don't have :current_password ... what should I do

Comment: current_password is just for example. it means the new_password that user will provide in the change password field